# Errors occured while trying to retrieve tweets

Tags: 7, social-network

I am running drupal 7 and using the following twitter module for twitter feed to display on the front page of a site.

`Twitter Pull   7.x-1.0-rc1 Pull Info from Twitter and Create Contextual Insets`

Recently, start getting the following error message instead of twitter feed

`Errors occured while trying to retrieve tweets. Please check Watchdog log messages.`

I don't have watchdog configured nor see any other error log that lead to anywhere. Please note that I am new to drupal. kindly let me know with detail steps how do I resolve this issue.

I see the following on `/admin/reports/dblog`

```
 Reports
 Status report
 Get a status report about your site's operation and any detected problems.
 Field list
 Overview of fields on all entity types.
```

This was working so I am sure the API keys were setup but I don't know where to look to confirm this.

Good idea to enable database logging. I have enabled the database logging now seeing more detail error message:

`Non-empty list of tweets returned blank space after applying theme function. Most probably you are passing invalid/unregistered theme key or tpl file corresponding to the theme key does not yet exist. Please fix the problem.`

I will check details on sendbox.

Comment: goto /admin/reports/dblog ... also did you setup the Twitter API keys?

Comment: @duckx thanks for the quick response. I have updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't enabled **Database Logging** yet, go ahead and do that on the modules page. Then you should see  errors reporting under **admin/reports/dblog**.

Twitter recently dropped their version 1 support, which is what Twitter Pull runs off of. Now you must use the Twitter and oAuth modules to deal with v1.1. Look at this [sandbox](https://drupal.org/sandbox/justindodge/2016387) for a solution. It branched off from Twitter Pull as an alternative to deal with oAuth tokens.

**Updated: Better way to do it**

There's recently a new module that came out that makes it a whole lot easier to embed tweets using the embedded widgets. Try [Twitter Block](https://drupal.org/project/twitter_block) instead, and you'll get up and running a lot faster.

Comment: +1 for using the Twitter and oAuth modules, there's a great deal of customization available via views for how it can be shown on your site also.

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter v1 API has now been replaced by v1.1 of the API, and as such it requires OAuth for even retrieving tweets. The Twitter Pull module was designed to easily pull tweets without any prior configuration since it used the old version of the API and as such, there are no plans to include OAuth integration, since the Twitter module performs this task now.

However, there is still a necessity for people using Twitter Pull blocks to have a working feed so they don't have to rebuild and redesign their blocks; but it requires Twitter & OAuth module integration now to restore this.

You can find a [patch to integrate Twitter & OAuth into Twitter Pull](https://drupal.org/node/1781024) to fix this and it should return your feeds to normal. The instructions are near the top of the thread.

Here's what I did when encountering the same problem:

- Turn off Twitter Pull
- Install and Enable Twitter, Oauth and Autoload.
- Enable Twitter Pull
- Register your application https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new
- Go to admin/settings/twitter/settings and copy in the OAuth settings from your new twitter app
- On the Twitter app settings page and paste in the callback URL displayed at admin/settings/twitter/settings
- On the Twitter app details page, click the “Create my access token” button at the bottom of the screen
- On your site, go to admin/settings/twitter and click “Go to twitter to add an authenticated account”, insert the account login
- Run cron to pull in the latest tweets to store in the database

This should renew your feed. There is no other solution I know of, but at least this method enables you to continue using Twitter Pull and not have to rebuild everything with just Twitter module.

Comment: Thanks for the detail response. I followed the link https://drupal.org/node/1781024 for the patch but wasn't able to locate clear instruction that you mentioned is "near the top". if possible, please update your answer with these instructions here. thanks!

Comment: It's the section that says: "If you DO want to use the Twitter and OAuth modules". You need to patch Twitter pull, then follow the instructions above. Good luck!

Comment: His instructions worked great for me!

Answer (score 0):

Check logs as possible things can be:

- Rate limit exceeded. Then use sandbox instead of testing.
- You're not using HTTPS for `api.twitter.com`, so check your configuration. Or module it-self hardcoding `http://`.
- [Twitter Pull module could be not compatible with Twitter module.](https://www.drupal.org/node/2562681)