# Feed Import (Twitter) via Cron

Tags: feeds, cron, importing-exporting

I'm using the Feeds Module to import Twitter Tweets as Nodes. As long as I start the import manually via www.yourdrupal.com/import everything works fine. But I want the Feed importer to start automatically every hour. Cron is activated, but nothing gets imported. I get an error on the statuspage "Token and secret MUST be string values."

My Feed import settings:
[image]

Protokoll Log: 
[image]

Feeds Log:
[image]

Debugging Info: "No channels ready to be executed, skipping cron."

Comment: May be it requires the api key and secret that you can get after creating a developer account at https://dev.twitter.com.

Comment: Well yes, but I inserted the API key etc under "http oAuth fetcher" and a manual import does import the tweets

Comment: So do you get any errors when the cron runs?

Comment: can you try debugging the cron callback codes so to log the token and secret key.

Comment: Can I do this via the Interface or do I have to add debugging code?

Comment: Debugging Info: "No channels ready to be executed, skipping cron."

Comment: just to confirm, though it may not have relation to main problem.Are you using elsyia cron module?If yes make your server crontab points to run elysia cron instead of core cron.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using this [sandbox (Twitter Pull)](https://drupal.org/sandbox/justindodge/2016387) for retrieving tweets instead. I've set it up before and it works quite well. You can see the relevant discussion below.

[Errors occured while trying to retrieve tweets](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79059/errors-occured-while-trying-to-retrieve-tweets/79060#79060)

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> No channels ready to be executed, skipping cron

sounds like it's related to [Elysia Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) module.

So please double check that you've followed the installation process ([`INSTALL.txt`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/elysia_cron/tree/INSTALL.txt?id=refs/heads;id2=7.x-1.x)), especially this part:

> To do this refer to the section "Configuring cron jobs" of drupal
>   documentation: http://drupal.org/cron
>
> The only difference is that you should use the `* * * * *` rule part
>   instead of `0 * * * *` or `45 * * * *` as described in the guide.
>
> While you're editing the system crontab, it's also recommended to
>   replace the `/cron.php` part with
>   `/sites/modules/elysia_cron/cron.php` (if you have installed
>   elysia_cron in `sites/modules` directory). This is an optional step
>   (you can leave `/cron.php` if you want), doing it will  result in a
>   better performance in bigger sites (elysia_cron's `cron.php` handles 
>   cache in a better way).
>
> For example:
>
> `* * * * * wget -O- -q -t 1 http://example.com/sites/all/modules/elysia_cron/cron.php`

You can also try to run cron from UI at `/admin/config/system/cron`.

If you're using drush, try `drush elysia-cron run`, instead of `drush cron`.

Check [`elysia_cron_run()`](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/elysia_cron/elysia_cron.module/function/elysia_cron_run/5) for execution logic.

Also check related Drupal issues: [#1748106](https://www.drupal.org/node/1748106), [#1952624](https://www.drupal.org/node/1952624).